# Javascript: How to pass in header token without quotes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, postman

I was given an api from a backend team.  When I test it using Postman, it works perfectly fine.  It requires a header set to **Authorization** and then the value is a token WITHOUT quotes.

However, I'm implementing in javascript and when I make an ajax call, I can't figure out how to send the value the same way I am in Postman without the quotes.  It keeps failing for me even when I try to do `.replace` to remove the quotes.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '____receiveNew/token',                           
     headers: {
       'Authorization': Cookies.getJSON.token
     },
     success: function(data)  { 
       // do whatever 
     }
 });
```

Comment: Where are the quotes coming from? Quotes are normally part of the language syntax, they're not actually in the strings.

Comment: You should probably be calling getJSON('token')

Comment: What does `console.log(Cookies.getJSON.token)` show?

Comment: I think they mean quotes in the value...

Comment: If it shows quotes around the value, that's just the way `console.log()` indicates that the value is a string, they're not actually part of the value.

Comment: @Barmar it shows quotes around it.  I did typeof(Cookies.getJSON.token) and it resulted in 'string'

Comment: Did it show `"value"` or `""value""`? If there's just one set of quotes around it, then those are just added by the console, they're not actually in the value.

Comment: just one set ...hmm.  I'm curious as to what my postman request is doing differently then

Comment: huh, strange.  I console logged the data in the `error` handler. and there's a responseText field in there which has the newly returned token value.  Why would this be coming back as a failure but still being successful?

Comment: ahh i didn't have 'dataType: text' set !

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it . let me know if it helps

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
        },
```